# Making docker images of Operating Systems

Tags: docker

I am still learning Docker and I like what I see, but most of the actions that you do are in the line of:

- Pull an image from the registry.
- Build something on top of that.
- Create an image out of that and save it.
- Run containers of that last image

This is fine, but suppose you want to make an image out of a new OS, and we only have an iso of that (for example, I don't think this is going to work with docker, but for example sake: an iso of Solaris 11.3). How can you make an image out of that (when it's to weird, you can take the next version of Fedora), when it is not already in some registry ?

Comment: Short story: you can't. Inside the iso that are programs that do the install and configuration. You could install the packages from the iso (if you know how to do it) to a specific directory and make an image from that.

Comment: Here are the relevant docket docs http://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/baseimages/